# Remap key bindings for dired mode

Tags: emacs, aquamacs

I am using Aquamacs 3.0a GNU Emacs 24.3.50.2

When ever I am in dired mode I find it very hard to navigate using `a` and `^`.
Can any one suggest more convenient key bindings so that it does not interfare with existing key bindings, and should only be active when in dired-mode only
May as convenient as `⌘+↓` to open and `⌘+↑` to parent dir, and `⌘M+↓` to open in new frame.

Comment: My suggestion would be to open up the three lisp files:  `dired-aux.el`; `dired-x.el`; `dired.el` and take a peek.  What you like and will reasonably use, leave alone.  What you think you will never use, you can take over the key-bindings or leave them alone or set them to `nil`.  What I did was *extremely drastic* -- I started off by having a user configuration file `(eval-after-load . . .)` that sets the lowercase and uppercase letters to `nil` e.g., `(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "a") nil) (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "A") nil)`  Then, I slowly enabled the bindings I use regularly.

Comment: I personally like enter to go in one directory deeper, and I like Ctrl+Alt+Command+Up to go up one directory -- i.e., `(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<C-M-s-up>") 'dired-up-directory)` You could, of course, use the same OSX Finder.app keybindings -- e.g., Command-Up to go up one directory.  Here is Command-Up:  `(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<s-up>") 'dired-up-directory)`  Here is Command-Down:  `(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<s-down>") 'dired-find-file)`  It's bedtime here were I am, so I'll let the other forum participants take over from here (e.g., your new frame request).

Comment: Oh, do yourself a favor, get a real version of Emacs for OSX:  http://emacsformacosx.com/  and if you would like to try out a developer build snapshot, there are nightly builds:  http://emacsformacosx.com/builds  Spend your time configuring that vanilla version.  In your spare time, play around with Aquamacs.  I learned a lot figuring out what makes Aquamacs tick, but in the end, the vanilla version is the way to go.  The only really useful feature of Aquamacs is the native spellchecker, but you'll find that Aspell with keyboard spell correction is more efficient than the mouse.

Comment: Clarifying question: are you asking how to rebind keys only in `dired` mode, or are you asking for suggestions about what key combinations to use?